# Как повесить один обработчик на несколько кнопок в jquary?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть несколько кнопок создающихся в цикле. Есть обработчик событий, надо чтоб он срабатывал по нажатию каждой кнопки и при этом знал, какая конкретно кнопка нажата. Как реализовать?

Comment: добавьте каждому блоку с кнопкой data-аттрибут и считывайте его. либо создайте input с параметром hidden и храните в нем информацию о нужной кнопке, которую так же потом считывайте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вешайте событие на класс. В `this` при этом у вас будет объект, который вызвал событие:

```
$('a.clickme').on('click', function() {
    console.log(this);
});
```

Comment: у меня сейчас так `        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#abtn').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
            })
        }` abtn это id, я изменил и теперь это класс, как мне это в обработчике написать?

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() { $('.abtn').click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); }) }` Только выборка по одному лишь классу - вещь ресурсоемкая, лучше сначала сужать выборку по тегу, как я писал выше: `a.abtn`, если объектом является ссылка.

Comment: Брррррррррррр...

Comment: @Qwertiy если ответ плохой - объясните, чем )

Comment: @NickVolynkin, как минимум тем, что он не работает с динамически созданными кнопками, о которых говорится в вопросе. Если, конечно, они не создаются до вызова этого скрипта, что было бы странно. А даже если так, то live-подписка тут всё равно кажется более логичной.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("div").on('click', "button", function (event) {
  $(this).css("color", "red");
});

$("div").html(Array(17).join("<button></button>"));
```

```css
body { counter-reset: i; }
button { counter-increment: i; }
button:after { content: counter(i); }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```